# Why is this DOM element shown greyed-out and isolated in Firebug?

Tags: dom, backbone.js, firebug, inspector

I have a Backbone application that appends elements to the DOM. When I log these DOM elements to the console, they sometimes appear greyed-out and isolated in the Firebug inspector, like this:

http://cl.ly/0N0s451G0W2L0x0r072r

Other times, they are shown in full colour and within the context of the DOM. Here is the same element, at a different time in my Backbone app:

http://cl.ly/2k2j0I3g2D0R0K121i3t

I'm guessing that a greyed-out, isolated treatment denotes an element that is not appended to the DOM—but I'm troubleshooting a bug in my app and it would be helpful to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guessed right. That "greyed-out" element is detached from DOM.